# How can I store a table containing expressions in gtable?

Tags: r, parsing, gwidgets

Say I have a table that has stored some things that happened during an R session:

```
steplist.table <- structure(list(auto.sum = structure(list(step1 = "summary1", 
    step2 = "summary2"), .Names = c("step1", "step2")), code = structure(list(
    step1 = "x(5)", step2 = print("boo")), .Names = c("step1", 
"step2")), enabled = structure(list(step1 = TRUE, step2 = TRUE), .Names = c("step1", 
"step2"))), .Names = c("auto.sum", "code", "enabled"), row.names = c("step1", 
"step2"), class = "data.frame")
```

or:

```
      auto.sum         code enabled
step1 summary1         x(5)    TRUE
step2 summary2 print("boo")    TRUE
```

I'd like to place this in a `gtable()` and then hide the `code` column from view. The `code` column needs to come along, because the user will make some changes to the table within the GUI. It looks like `gtable()` evaluates the expressions in the `code` column, though, and it definitely doesn't appear properly.

example:

```
library(gWidgets)
mygw <- gwindow()
gtable(steplist.table, container = mygw, filter.column = "code")
```

The above code will actually print "boo", (while leaving the string `"x(5)"` alone), which is not good.

I was planning on inserting the code using the convenient `quote()` as was done above with `print(boo)`, but if there's a workaround that involves creating sanitized R code strings that can also be parsed by the interpreter, I'm happy to use that instead. I haven't been able to find it yet.

Comment: Posting code using functions from unnamed packages is at worst impolite, and at the very least limits your audience to either current users of such packages or those who are willing to hunt them down.

Comment: Whoops, did you mean the `library()` line? Added.

Comment: In `gWidgets2` the code column renders as a string. However, the `gtable` method shows all the columns by default. A possible workaround (untested) would be to set the column width to 0. For specific toolkits, it may be possible to cook up a command to hide a column. Which toolkit are you using? (By the way, it is worthwhile using `gWidgets2` -- there are some API changes, though minor and it is much easier for me to fix things and push these changes out.

Comment: @jverzani I'm trying to stay mostly toolkit agnostic, but testing on GTK2. Mainly I'm concerned about keeping the `code` column unevaluated, although eventually I want to hide it. Have I misunderstood the purpose of `filter.column`?

Comment: The `filter.column` is just a column number so that the filter function has a column of data to filter against. It is not present in `gWidgets2`, as it is really best with Gtk, not tcltk. Best to use the `visible<-` method to control which rows are displayed. As for evaluating the `code` column, I don't think that happens in `gWidgets2`, though I would guess it doesn't as well in `gWidgets`, so may be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fairly robust solution that at least addresses placing the `code` within a string, insulating it from possible evaluation during the process of assignment:

```
new.step <- list(summary = step.summary,
                 enabled = FALSE,
                 code = paste(deparse(
                                bquote(do.call(.(func.name), .(step.args))),
                                # ensure we get knittable code
                                control = c("showAttributes" = NULL)),
                              collapse = "\n")
                        )
```

There are a few things going on here:

- In order for the code to be useful for anything later, arguments that need to be dereferenced can be evaluated inside a larger quoted expression with `.()` when inside `bquote()`.
- `deparse()` will convert the resulting `call` object to a string, but it usually includes a bunch of metadata-like stuff, wrapping the elements inside `structure()` calls. This confuses `knitr`, so we drop it with `"showAttributes" = NULL`, which strips it from `deparse`'s opts list for this call.
- Finally, the resulting expression comes with newlines that `parse` will interpret as character vector delimiters, so we collapse the result with newlines, which was the apparent original intent of the formatting of the resulting `deparse()` call.

As a kludge, the `code` element is placed last in the list, ensuring that when converted to a named column in the `gtable` dataframe, it will be rightmost (and out of view in my use case).

---

I'm going to go soak my head in an ice bucket now and try to forget about metaprogramming.